# Android NDK and ALSA

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, alsa

Hello I have a library that is compiled under the Android NDK. This library for audio uses ALSA.

Question - is it possible to play audio in Android through the  ALSA? If so, whether it is necessary for this to compile ALSA for NDK?

Comment: I already thought about doing that too. The kernel interface is there and the alsa library sources are on http://android.git.kernel.org/, but it's currently down for maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

There was alsa-lib project in external in android sources. Android itself uses ALSA for playing audio.

Android sources are not browsable just now (404).